# C# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы

Tags: c#

Я всего несколько дней осваиваю C# (новичок) и всё было нормально, использовал кириллицу в своих задачках. И неожиданно  для меня вместо русских букв начали появляться знаки вопроса, это я пофиксил `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` Но когда я вывожу текст в консоль через **ReadLine** появились снова вопросительные знаки. Суть вопроса в том, что бы заменить эти вопросительные знаки на русс. Надеюсь тут мне помогут) Спасибо.
UPD: Поставил **chcp** на нужный, но при повторной проверке обнаружил что он слетел обратно(851) Как убрать что бы он сам не ставился?

Код `string Name; Console.WriteLine("Имя?"); Name = Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine("Твоё имя " + Name);`

[image: Вот как-то так]

Comment: Он похож только из-за начальной проблемы. В моём случае через ReadLine выводятся вопросительные знаки, вместо кириллицы

Comment: Покажите лучше код. Дополните вопрос кодом.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` не выводит текст в консоль. Возможно, вы что-то другое имеете ввиду?

Comment: Скорее всего, нужно явно задать кодировку не только вывода на консоль, но и ввода с консоли. Попробуйте добавить `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: @MaxS Теперь кириллица и вовсе исчезла при выводе. но латиницу выводит спокойно [https://imgur.com/a/uCLvnZd ]

Comment: Мне не на чем проверить, у меня всё ок в консоли. Попробуйте поиграться с кодировкой  InputEncoding. Например, использовать `Encoding.Default` или `Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: @MaxS Попробовал оба варианта, к сожалению ничего не изменилось. Не так я себе представлял первые дни обучения =)

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` тоже не работает?

Comment: @MaxS Я кажется понял в чем проблема. У меня сам меняется **chcp** . Не знаете как это убрать?

Comment: Возможно, эта ссылка вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line